# eBay API - List an item with 'Local Pick up' shipping method

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ebay-api

I am a .NET developer. I am working on listing an item whose shipping method I want to set it as `"Local Pick up"`. I referred to the API doc which says `"LocalDelivery"` should be used to define `shippingmethod` for `Local Pick up`. I did that and tried listing it on US sandbox. But then it gave me an exception:

> Shipping Service Local Delivery/Pickup(15) is deprecated and mapped to Local Pickup(150).

Here is my code example:

```
ShippingServiceOptionsType shippingOptions = new ShippingServiceOptionsType();
shippingOptions.ShippingService = "LocalDelivery";
shippingOptions.ShippingServicePriority = 1;
shippingOptions.LocalPickup = true;
shippingOptions.FreeShippingSpecified = false;
```

Any ideas? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you defined `ShippingService` as `"LocalDelivery"` it should be `"LocalPickup"`. i.e.

```
shippingOptions.ShippingService = "LocalPickup";
```